# Rollback update if after update trigger fails in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, rollback, database-trigger

What happens if, after updating the table, trigger fails for any reason in Oracle11g. Will original update rollback? If not, how to enforce performing rollback in case of failure.

Comment: You could create a sample table, a trigger and check what happens. If you have doubts with what you get, or you need to do something different, post a question here, together with your the results of your research and your attempts.

Comment: Initial testing before applying into production showed the support of rollback. However, I observed few records are not update accordingly in heavy multi-thread requests. As this is a production issue and I am in shortage of time, I raised this question to ensure about THE CONCEPT in order to look for problem anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As should be in any DB, Statements are atomic in Oracle. Transaction won't be completed, and any DML action occured during transaction process will be rolledback.